# Delay between TradingView → Telegram → Cornix

Tags: telegram, tradingview-api

I am creating a script that will send signals to a Telegram group (TG) from which Cornix will read those signals and, through the APIs, send those "trades" to your set exchange. So a classic Signal Channel on TG.

The problem I am getting is that when an entry price gets detected, the exchange does not get that trade in time.

By that I mean it takes too much time for the script to send the signal on Telegram and too much time for Cornix to send the trade through.

By the time Cornix opens the limit order, that entry price has already changed, so I have to hope that the price gets hit again, which as you can guess, is not ideal.

Currently I am using the 5 TF. I tried the 15 minutes time frame. Both have the same issue.

Is there a way to fix this delay or somehow reduce it?

Comment: What is *"TF"*? *"Time frame"*? *"TradingView"* something? *"Telegram"* something?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve also noticed delays from TradingView (TV) to my bots and it doesn’t really matter which ones. However, I have noticed that TV signals mostly are delayed a few seconds in time. Then in my case it goes to a bot and then from bot to exchange, so there will naturally be a delay from signal to exchange and actually placing the order.

Bot to [Binance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binance) has taken some 1.5 minutes to trade, and you are right: Sometimes the price moves quickly. Maybe set market orders to buy and see how it goes. I’d be interested if you find a quicker solution.